# QGIS measure tool reporting distances of only 0.00m

Tags: qgis, measurements

I have an orthographic projection as a raster layer, a point layer, and a polygon layer all in CRS EPSG:6543. I am attempting to use the measure tool to collect the length of my polygon and other objects in the ortho projection, but the tool will only report values of 0.00m after segments are drawn.
What could I check to troubleshoot or should I just start a new file? Have 3 files while 1 works the other two do not.

[image: image shows a segment drawn down the length of the rectangle while the measure tool returns values of 0]